# How to connect to containerized database with its IP?

Tags: postgresql, docker, localhost, host

I'm new to Docker. I successfully created a PostgreSQL container my-database and I am able to access it from SQLTools on my local machine with server address **localhost** and the port.

I got the containerized database's *IP address* from the following command:

```
docker container inspect my-database
```

But when I go back to SQLTools or the PHP web application (not containerized) and try to connect to my-database with the IP address I got above, it couldn't connect successfully.

What am I missing here?

FYI, I also created another container and was able to connect to my-database with the following way: Use the same network for both my-database and the second container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you enable access to the database.

If your php service runs in the same machine, then localhost could work
If its on a different machine in the same network, then use the network IP assigned to that machine. If you have your php server in a totally different  location, then you may want to use something like an nginx reverse proxy to your docker container.

So in your case you should get the ip:port where your db container runs and use that. Docker inspect shows the internal network ip which only helps other containers in the same virtual network connect to a container.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Gabriel! How can I get the ip:port where my db container runs instead of docker inspect? FYI, I am trying to access to the containerized database from 1, php application built from XAMPP. 2, SQLTools extension in VS Code(I am able to use it to connect the containerized database with localhost, but I still want to know how to access with db container's IP address.)

Answer (score 0):

You never need the `docker inspect` IP address.  You can only connect to it in two specific circumstances: if you're in a different container on the same Docker network, or if you're (a) not in a container at all, (b) on the same host, and (c) that host is running native Linux and not a different OS.

You've already identified the right answers.  Say you start the container as

```sh
docker network create any-network-name
docker run \
  --name database \
  --net any-network-name \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  postgres
```

From another Docker container on the `any-network-name` network, you can use the `database` container name as a DNS name, and avoid the manual IP lookup; ignore any `-p` options and use the "normal" port for the service.  From outside a container, you can use the host's DNS name or IP address (or, if it's the same host, `localhost`) and the first `-p` port number.

If you're running this in Docker Compose, it automatically creates a network for you and registers containers under their Compose service name; you do not need `networks:`, `container_name:`, or other similar settings.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    ports: ['5432:5432']
  application:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PGHOST=postgres
```